# Moving the content of a UIStackView inwards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a `UIScrollView` setup, laid out as shown below. The content of this is currently right at the edge (left and right, at least) of the view. I want this to be moved inwards/padded by say ~10 points.
However, everything I have tried so far results in horizontal scrolling - I only want to be able to scroll vertically.
I've already tried adding +10 to the leading/trailing constraints, which again causes horizontal scrolling to be possible. The same applies when using `contentInset`.
Would prefer to be able to sort this in the storyboard if possible.

[image: Storyboard layout]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: @DevilDecoder yes I think so - how do I double check? Sorry I'm pretty new to iOS development.

Comment: i can see you have used constraints i can see it below view hierarchy left side in image

Comment: @DevilDecoder Oh those. Yeah I mentioned them in the initial question.

Comment: what is distribution stack views

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is constraining the `width` of your stack view to the `width` of the **main view**.

Instead, constrain your stack view `10` for Leading and Trailing (related to the scroll view), and constrain the stack view's `width` to the scroll view's `width - 20` (10 for each side).

Your constraints should then look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the suggestions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/9dhmsm/moving_the_content_of_a_uistackview_inwards/), namely using `UIStackView`'s built in layout margins.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I pretty much did - I didn’t realise that UIStackView had inbuilt layout margins, and using them solved my issue - which I stated above.